# MariaDB - aggregated count in group

Tags: mariadb

Suppose there is a table:

```
first   second  third
1       1       1
1       1       1
1       2       2
1       1       2
2       3       1
```

And by query:

```
SELECT first, count(*) AS cnt
FROM table
GROUP BY first
```

We get result:

```
first   cnt
1       4
2       1
```

How to calculate count of another column (columns) inside group?
Expected result:

```
first   cnt aggregated_count_by_second  aggregated_count_by_third
1       4   {1: 3, 2: 1}                {1: 2, 2: 2}
2       1   {3: 1}                      {1: 1}
```

DB version: 10.3.39-MariaDB-0+deb10u1

Comment: What data type are you expecting `aggregated_count_by_second` to be?

Comment: no matter what type, i suppose there is only one possibility here - strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ask another question if you change it.

For the original quetion you could do :

```
select 
  first, 
  sum(c) as cnt, 
  concat('{', group_concat(concat(second ,':', c )), '}') as aggregated_count_by_second
from (
  select first, second, count(second) as c
  from tableA
  group by first, second
) AS q
group by first;
```

See a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/z5OIDNfO).

And a quick version for the second one:

```
select first, cnt, max(aggregated_count_by_second), max(aggregated_count_by_third)
from (
select 
  first, 
  sum(s) as cnt, 
  concat('{', group_concat(concat(second ,':', s )), '}') as aggregated_count_by_second,
  null as aggregated_count_by_third
from (
  select first, second, count(second) as s
  from tableA
  group by first, second
) AS q
group by first
union
select 
  first, 
  sum(t) as cnt, 
  null,
  concat('{', group_concat(concat(third ,':', t )), '}') 
from (
  select first, third, count(third) as t
  from tableA
  group by first, third
) AS q
group by first
) as q1
group by first, cnt
```

See a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qSsUEqXw)

Comment: Yes, I slightly complicated the question :) Because, actually, there are several columns such as "second" column.

Comment: @holden321 Please do not do that. Respect the time of those who help you.